# Extracting channel subscribers for a content owner

Tags: youtube-api

I want to extract subscribers to channels using content owner authorisation.

This query works but of course returns subscribers to the cms account.

```
v3.channels().\
list(part=parts, mySubscribers=True,
     maxResults=50, pageToken=nextPageToken,
     onBehalfOfContentOwner=partner_code).execute()
```

Using the [youtube api documentation for listing subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) as reference, it doesn't seem possible.

This surprises me. Am I missing something?

Comment: are you only trying to get the subscribers? cause you don't need to authenticate as the user for that.

Answer (score 0):

This code in Java API worked for me:

```java
youtube
    .subscriptions()
    .list("subscriberSnippet")
    .setMySubscribers(true)
    .setOnBehalfOfContentOwner(CONTENT_OWNER_ID)
    .setOnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel(CHANNEL_ID)
    .setOauthToken(YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN).execute();
```